# Error setting up Poetry environment for new project on PyCharm on Windows -- older projects working fine

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-poetry

I have several projects that I've managed to set up poetry environments on.
However, when trying to set up a poetry environment on a new project following the usual procedure ([as described by PyCharm here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/poetry.html#poetry-env) .

However, after selecting the local interpreter and poetry executable, I keep getting the following error:

```
Creating virtualenv pythonproject-NZhFQb8F-py3.11 in C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs

Command ['C:\\Users\\[USER]\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\Local\\pypoetry\\Cache\\virtualenvs\\pythonproject-NZhFQb8F-py3.11\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-I', '-W', 'ignore', '-'] errored with the following return code 101

Error output:
Unable to create process using '"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe" -I -W ignore -'


Input:
import sys

if hasattr(sys, "real_prefix"):
    print(sys.real_prefix)
elif hasattr(sys, "base_prefix"):
    print(sys.base_prefix)
else:
    print(sys.prefix)
```

The toml file is created though, but running any poetry commands, such as `poetry add pandas` will return the same error message.

Everything is set up exactly the same for my older projects and working, each with their own lock and toml files.

I'm using poetry version 1.6.1 and python 3.11.5 and PyCharm 2023.1.3 (Community Edition).

I have tried reinstalling poetry and selecting different python executables that I find the directory, including python.exe, python3.11.exe, python3.exe, pythonw.exe, pythonw311.exe.

Comment: What does happen when you run the same Python command with the same absolute path from the command line?

Comment: I get "Unable to create process using..." then the path.

Comment: The Python installation might be damaged somehow.